# How to integrate Application Insights with PHP Azure Web App?

Tags: php, azure, azure-application-insights

I've deployed a PHP web app on Azure with Application Insights turned on, with Application Insights Extension added and I still don't see any data inside the Applications Insight blade. So now I wonder if there are any additional steps required? :)

After going through couple of howto's I see that they mostly cover .NET, so maybe lack of data on the Application Insights blade means that PHP isn't actually supported (yet)?

Additionally, I wonder if there is a way to stream Diagnostics logs from PHP web app into Application Insights?

Kind regards,

Leszek

PS.
I see CPU, memory, # of requests on the application blade in Metrics Per Instance , but somehow they dont get propagated to Application Insights (I assume they should be :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP you have to use specific extension - https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-PHP

Comment: Interesting thank you, do I also need to use it to catch basic # of requests, CPU metrics or (if I read docs correctly) it's more for in-app custom events? If the latter - any idea if the standard instance metrics like CPU, HTTP requests, etc should be pushed to Application Insights automatically?

Comment: at this point you pretty much have to do everything manually using the sdk, including requests.  If you're a PHP expert, i'd suggest making contributions back to the SDK yourself to make it better, if you can.  (i haven't done any real PHP in like a decade but i did add support for something like beginRequest/endRequest a while back)

Comment: It looks like that repo is archived.  Is there a replacement for it or a newer answer that doesn't involve a 3rd party extension?

Comment: The current position I believe is to use Open Telemetry adoption and keep working on adopting new languages. It appears PHP has an pre-release alpha - https://opentelemetry.io/docs/php/